# Call method without using static class name before method name c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**My question is** - How can i call my method GetISystemManager without using class name References before Method name? Why is this possible in the first example, but not in the second?

1. If I use the UnityEngine namespace in a Unity project, I can use method e.g. `FindObjectOfType` without specifying any static class before the method name:

Method:

```
public static T FindObjectOfType<T>() where T : Object;
```

Call:

```
cM = FindObjectOfType<CameraManager>();
```

2. I created a similar method which is in my static class `References`, but I can only call it with "References." before the method name.

Method:

```
 public static T GetISystemComponent<T>() where T : ISystemComponent
    {
        foreach(ISystemComponent sC in systemComponentList)
        {
            if(sC.GetType().Equals(typeof(T)))
            {
                return (T)sC;
            }
        }
       Debug.LogError(typeof(T) + " - this component not exist in systemComponentList." );
       return default(T);
    }
```

Call:

```
mM = Reference.GetISystemComponent<MazeManager>();
```

This is a method i am talking about in Unity.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried ```using static References;```?

Comment: I don't mind; it's bordering on rude but you have the option of clicking the flag next to it and reporting it as unfriendly or unkind. Launching into someone doesn't de-escalate anything

Comment: Let me try to offer a compromise, in order to help with calming down. I try to do this without taking sides. "StackOverflow aims to be a collection of clear programming questions with helpful answers. Basic concepts can be asked about in a focused way, i.e. it must be possible to answer them without ending up being a tutorial."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class of the first example most probably inherits from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) or [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) which both inherit from [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) -> it **is** a `UnityEngine.Object` and can therefore directly use its methods.

---

Besides that and in general you can also always add a [`using static <namespace.type>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)

```
using static UnityEngine.Object;
```

on top of a script and then use any static method (actually member) of `UnityEngine.Object` without everytime writing `UnityEngine.Object` in front of it.

Comment: Yeah no multi inheritance was never a thing in `c#` or any object oriented language I know ... what you can do though instead of inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` make your own in between base class `public class ExtendedMonoBeuaviour : MonoBehaviour { public static T YourMethod<T>(); }` .. and now other classes can instead of inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` rather simply inherit from `ExtendedMonoBehaviour` and use all it's implementations ... This is again limited to one base class of course

Comment: So this is exactly what i was looking for.I have ExtendedMonoBehaviour class what inherit from MonoBehaviour so i can use both MyExtended Methods + UnityDefault methods , thank you so much